# How to setup dev environment on Github codespaces to contribute to Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, open-source, development-environment, github-codespaces

I grew an interest in contributing to Rails after watching [Eileen's Talk](https://youtu.be/7zoD6NZy6vY). To make things easier, I forked the repo and I opened it in Github Codespaces. After running `bundle install`, I wanted to run some tests but I kept getting this error:

```
Your lockfile doesn't include a valid resolution.
You can fix this by regenerating your lockfile or trying to manually editing the bad locked gems to a version that satisfies all dependencies.
The unmet dependencies are:
* activesupport (>= 3.0, < 6.2), depended upon delayed_job-4.1.9, unsatisfied by activesupport-7.1.0.alpha
* activerecord (>= 3.0, < 6.2), depended upon delayed_job_active_record-4.1.6, unsatisfied by activerecord-7.1.0.alpha
```

I tried updating bundler and downgrading the gems in questions to fix the dependency issue. Neither worked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the Rails core team member Rafael França](https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/issues-with-github-codespaces-setup-to-contribute-to-rails/79731/2?u=pantomath):

> This “error” is just a warning. It should not impact the setup, and you can just ignore it.